# Using RegionPlot to draw inequality involving Nintegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I'm trying to draw the region where the next inequality is true  : $$ r_1 \tau-r_3 \int^{\tau}_{0} C_s(t)<0$$where $$C_s(t)=e^{t-r_5 t} \left(d e^{r_8 \tau }+e^{r_8 (t+\tau )}-e^{r_8 t}\right){}^{-\frac{1}{r_8}} \left(\int_1^t r_4 e^{\xi  \left(r_5-1\right)} \left(d e^{r_8 \tau }+e^{\xi  r_8} \left(e^{r_8 \tau }-1\right)\right){}^{\frac{1}{r_8}} \, d\xi -\int_1^0 r_4 e^{\xi  \left(r_5-1\right)} \left(d e^{r_8 \tau }+e^{\xi  r_8} \left(e^{r_8 \tau }-1\right)\right){}^{\frac{1}{r_8}} \, d\xi \right) $$ varying the parameters $\tau$ and $d$, with $ r_5$ and $r_8$ fixed.  Since i have not been able to solve the integrals explicitly I'm using NIntegrate to evaluate it. First i have definition of $C_s$ like this

```
Subscript[C, s][t_, \[Tau]_, d_] := (E^(t - t*Subscript[r, 5])*
(-Integrate[E^(\[Xi]*(-1 + Subscript[r, 5]))*(d*E^(\[Tau]*Subscript[r, 8]) + 
      E^(\[Xi]*Subscript[r, 8])*(-1 + E^(\[Tau]*Subscript[r, 8])))^(1/Subscript[r, 8])*
    Subscript[r, 4], {\[Xi], 1, 0}] + Integrate[E^(\[Xi]*(-1 + Subscript[r, 5]))*
   (d*E^(\[Tau]*Subscript[r, 8]) + E^(\[Xi]*Subscript[r, 8])*
      (-1 + E^(\[Tau]*Subscript[r, 8])))^(1/Subscript[r, 8])*Subscript[r, 4], 
  {\[Xi], 1, t}]))/(-E^(t*Subscript[r, 8]) + d*E^(\[Tau]*Subscript[r, 8]) + 
 E^((t + \[Tau])*Subscript[r, 8]))^(1/Subscript[r, 8])
```

then in order to evaluate $\int^{\tau}_{0} C(t)$ I create the function:

```
Subscript[r, 1] = 0.00029938135;
Subscript[r, 3] = 2.507341314*^-8;
Subscript[r, 5] = 0.005435396430;
Subscript[r, 8] = 0.5761520216;
Subscript[r, 4] = 0.00001129433024;
NIntCs[\[Tau]_, d_] := 
     NIntegrate[Subscript[C, s][t, \[Tau], d], {t, 0, \[Tau]}]
```

. 
Which allows me to evaluate the integral $\int^{\tau}_{0} C_s(t)$  for example, from $0$ to $\tau=48$ with $d=10^8$ :

```
 In[94]:=
NIntCs[48, 10^8]

Out[94]= 1.02318*10^10
```

Now if if execute RegionPlot to see the inequality

```
RegionPlot[Subscript[r, 1]*\[Tau] - Subscript[r, 3]*NIntCs[\[Tau], d] < 0, {\[Tau], 0, 10}, {d, 0, 10}]
```

Throws :

```
In[93]:=
RegionPlot[Subscript[r, 1]*\[Tau] - Subscript[r, 3]*NIntCs[\[Tau], d] < 0, {\[Tau], 0, 10}, 
  {d, 0, 10}]

During evaluation of In[93]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level. >>

During evaluation of In[93]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level. >>

During evaluation of In[93]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[0.193382 +0.372841 $Failed] returned to top level. >>

During evaluation of In[93]:= General::stop: Further output of Throw::nocatch will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[93]= Hold[Throw[False], Throw[False], Throw[0.193382 + 0.372841 $Failed], 
 Throw[False], Throw[False], Throw[0.28262 + 0.751145 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.97354 + 0.370967 $Failed], Throw[0.158068 + 0.405859 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.591793 + 0.932639 $Failed], Throw[0.0379657 + 0.669591 $Failed], 
 Throw[{{-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    433906005514 - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], -1 + \[Tau]}, {{-433906005514 + 
      753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 
     1, Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + \[Tau], 1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1], \[Tau]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {\[Tau], 1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    433906005514 - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], -1 + \[Tau]}, {{-433906005514 + 
      753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 
     1, Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + \[Tau], 1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[0.55161 + 0.751459 $Failed], Throw[0.839512 + 0.769479 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.0342406 + 0.286654 $Failed], Throw[0.367282 + 0.209207 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.543596 + 0.737445 $Failed], Throw[0.588095 + 0.707536 $Failed], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], -1 + t, 
    433906005514 \[Tau] - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + t, 1, 
     t}, {433906005514 \[Tau] - 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
     1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], Reduce`ReduceVar[3], Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1], \[Xi]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[4]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {\[Xi], 1, \[Xi]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 
    t}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {t, 1, t}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], -1 + t, 
    433906005514 \[Tau] - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + t, 1, 
     t}, {433906005514 \[Tau] - 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
     1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], Reduce`ReduceVar[3], Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1], \[Xi]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[4]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {\[Xi], 1, \[Xi]}}}], 
 Throw[0.896879 + 0.796894 $Failed], Throw[0.245253 + 0.107569 $Failed], 
 Throw[-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x] + 
   Derivative[1][Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y][
    NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x], 
  NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation], 
 Throw[-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x] + 
   Derivative[1][Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y][
    NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x], 
  NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation], 
 Throw[0.100299 + 0.716852 $Failed], Throw[0.087617 + 0.15486 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.912248 + 0.262896 $Failed], Throw[0.75313 + 0.621968 $Failed], 
 Throw[{{-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    433906005514 - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], -1 + \[Tau]}, {{-433906005514 + 
      753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 
     1, Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + \[Tau], 1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1], \[Tau]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {\[Tau], 1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    433906005514 - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], -1 + \[Tau]}, {{-433906005514 + 
      753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {-433906005514 + 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 
     1, Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + \[Tau], 1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[0.889982 + 0.174676 $Failed], Throw[0.350523 + 0.740018 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.65878 + 0.55734 $Failed], Throw[0.376622 + 0.257991 $Failed], 
 Throw[0.833684 + 0.0358738 $Failed], Throw[0.330488 + 0.341129 $Failed], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], -1 + t, 
    433906005514 \[Tau] - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + t, 1, 
     t}, {433906005514 \[Tau] - 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
     1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], Reduce`ReduceVar[3], Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1], \[Xi]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[4]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {\[Xi], 1, \[Xi]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 
    t}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {t, 1, t}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], -1 + t, 
    433906005514 \[Tau] - 
     753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1] - Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {-1 + t, 1, 
     t}, {433906005514 \[Tau] - 753110271565 Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 
     1, \[Tau]}}}], 
 Throw[{{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], Reduce`ReduceVar[3], Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 
    Reduce`ReduceVar[1], \[Xi]}, {{Reduce`ReduceVar[4], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[4]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[3], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[3]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[2], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[2]}, {Reduce`ReduceVar[1], 1, 
     Reduce`ReduceVar[1]}, {\[Xi], 1, \[Xi]}}}], 
 Throw[0.955508 + 0.0216473 $Failed], Throw[0.32874 + 0.738323 $Failed], 
 Throw[-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x] + 
   Derivative[1][Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y][
    NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x], 
  NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation], 
 Throw[-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x] + 
   Derivative[1][Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y][
    NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x], 
  NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation]]
```

How i can use RegionPlot to draw the inequality?, also speed up tips would be useful. Than you.

Comment: Advise that you replace `C[t_, \[Tau]_, d_] := (*defined like above*)` with the actual Mathematica code. Fine to have the nice pretty printed equation in addition to the Mathematica code.

Comment: General recommendation is to avoie upper case user defined symbols. Currently I get an error with `C[t_, \[Tau]_, d_] := ...`

Comment: Thank you @ Jack LaVigne i have made the changes.

Comment: Are `r1` through `r8` constants? You need to supply us with the values. Is `t` always greater than one or between one and zero? I think you can perform one integration rather than two by changing the limits because the function inside the integral is identical.

Comment: @ Jack LaVigne Yes, r1,r3,r5,r8 are fixed parameters. I Just added it.And for my case t is  greater than 1. I'm thinking about the changing of limits.

Comment: Subscript[r, 4] = 0.00001129433024

Answer (score 1):

`RegionPlot` does indeed produce an error. I have contacted Wolfram support with this example.

They suggested a workaround using `Plot3D` and `RegionFunction`.

```
r1 = 0.00029938135; r3 = 2.507341314*^-8;
r4 = 0.00001129433024; r5 = 0.005435396430;
r8 = 0.5761520216;

cs[t_?NumericQ, τ_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := Exp[t - t*r5]*
  NIntegrate[Exp[ξ*(-1 + r5)]*(d*Exp[τ*r8] + Exp[ξ*r8]*
         (-1 + Exp[τ*r8]))^(1/r8)*r4, {ξ, 0, t}]/
   (-Exp[t*r8] + d*Exp[τ*r8] + Exp[(t + τ)*r8])^(1/r8)

nIntCs[τ_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[cs[t, τ, d], {t, 0, τ}]
```

The evaluation is slow but the function `nIntCs` plots OK.

```
Plot3D[
 Evaluate[nIntCs[τ, d]], {τ, -0.5, 0.5}, {d, 0, 10},
 AxesLabel -> {"τ", "d", "intCs"},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]],
 ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below the expression that is used as the input to `RegionPlot` is displayed along with the plane `z=0`. Take note that the region that is less than zero is totally dominated by the term `r1 τ`. The product `r3 NIntCs[τ, d]` has virtually no effect on the result.

```
Show[
 Plot3D[r1 τ - r3 Evaluate[nIntCs[τ, d]],
  {τ, -0.5, 0.5}, {d, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"τ", "d", "intCs"},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]
  ],
 Plot3D[0, {τ, -0.5, 0.5}, {d, 0, 10},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Cyan]
  ],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The workaround to `RegionPlot` using `Plot3D` and `RegionFunction` is shown below.

```
Plot3D[
 r1 τ - r3*Evaluate[NIntCs[τ, d]], 
 {τ, -0.5, 0.5}, {d, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"τ", "d", "intCs"}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]],
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   (r1 x - r3*Evaluate[NIntCs[x, y]] < 0)],
 ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]